# Unable to generate jax-ws classes from wsdl in mule studio

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, mule, mule-studio

How do I configure mule to use a class customization tool when generating the JAX-WS classes from a WSDL?

I cannot modify the WSDL and I get the following error in Mule Studio:

"A class/interface with the same name "xxx.xxx" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict."

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run `wsimport` with the `-B-XautoNameResolution` (no spaces)